# Kendo UI Datetimepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI datetimepicker and while clicking on the calendar icon, I am getting the following error:-

```
this.IntlService.weekendRange is not a function
at MonthViewService.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/dist/fesm5/index.js.MonthViewService.isWeekend
```

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.